# how to make django's choice option dynamic in the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating a reference lexicon in django.  The lexicon is a translator for certain fields from one language to another.

The lexicon goes like this:  `'id','lng1','lng2','lng3'`
I have a model that uses the lexicon in one of the fields.

```
class lexicon(models.Model):
    lng1 = model.Charfield(max_length=255)
    lng2 = model.Charfield(max_length=255)
    lng3 = model.Charfield(max_length=255)

lexicon_choices = (
  (lng1=lng1),
  (lng2=lng2),
  (lng3=lng3)
)


class model(models:Model):
    model_name = model.Charfield(max_length=255, unique)
    field1 = model.Charfield(max_length=3,CHOICES=lexicon_choices)
```

This works ok, but I want to know, is there a way to glean out the column names from `class lexicon` and port them as the choices for `class model`?  I am using Django Rest Framework for the first time, and I want to make sure the right `lng` is there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ForeignKey` on the `lexicon` class to your main model. This will ensure a One to Many relationship. And you can store the values in database.

Comment: That's my problem.  The ForeignKey could change.  ModalA->lng1, ModelB->lng3, etc....  Thanks.

Comment: besides, in my mind, ModalA should connect to lexicon.id, so I can convert lng1 to lng2 at a later date

Comment: By using a foreign key, you will connect to the `lexicon.id`. You can add one more field to detect which one is selected, like `lng1` or `lng2`

Answer (score 1):

yes, possible. but in admin.py

```
class CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = [(x.id, x.name) for x in Lexicon.objects.all()]
        self.fields['field1'].choices = choices

class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CustomForm
```

and your original model looks like:

```
class YourModel(models:Model):
    model_name = model.Charfield(max_length=255, unique)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(('--', '--'),))
```

**IMPORTANT**: do **not** name your class names with lower case. ;)

Comment: Ok, I think, this will help you only in admin... you need this also in frontend?